# I have been training my image classification model using Keras. After I increased the number of categories from 3 to 4 I got an error?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, neural-network

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

file_1 = '/Users/harshpanwar/Desktop/paneer/butter/2.jpg'

predicted_img = image.load_img(file_1, target_size=(150, 150))

predicted_img = image.img_to_array(predicted_img)

predicted_img = np.expand_dims(predicted_img, axis=0)
predicted_img = predicted_img/255
prediction_prob = model.predict(predicted_img)
model.predict_classes(predicted_img)
# Output prediction

print(f'Probability that food image is of paneer is: {prediction_prob} ')
```

Output generated:

Probability that food image is of paneer is: [[1.1548113e-02 9.9347383e-01 1.1212566e-05 0.0000000e+00]]

With only three categories the output was coming out to be simple percentage but after changing the number of categories to 4 the values are coming in the wrong format -> [[1.1548113e-02 9.9347383e-01 1.1212566e-05 0.0000000e+00]]

Comment: What have you changed? Where have you changed? Whats does your model look like? What is input and output shapes of your model?

Comment: @VivekMehta Actually I got the answer. I hadn't restarted the kernel after changing the no. of categories from 3 to 4.